# Modifying pip/conda packages inside site-packages

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda

Is modifying Anaconda/pip packages (adding files, changing existing file contents when e.g. applying a fix that hasn't been pushed as the latest release on pip/conda) in `envs/<env_name>/Lib/site-packages/<package_name>` a good idea or not? Can this cause conflicts when updating in the future?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's a very bad idea. It won't cause conflicts, instead, all of your changes will be lost when you update the package.

Rather find the package's repository, clone it, make your changes and install it from the repository or from a directory (outside of `site-packages`).

Check the Pip documentation on how to install from a VCS or local directory: https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#installing-packages.

It's as simple as:

```
pip install -e path/to/SomePackage
# or
$ pip install -e git+https://github.com/username/package.git#egg=hyde
```

Comment: I don't see how it's a very bad idea since the changes are included in the next release anyway. All I was afraid of is corrupting my conda install, pip, or one of the environments, like I've done so many times in the past.. Based on your answer, that won't happen.

Comment: @stackexchange_account1111 the risk I anticipate relates to Conda's reliance on hardlinking. A theoretically worrisome example would be a change to an existing file that references a new file. If the existing file is hardlinked to the package cache and other environments, then it would be changed there as well, but the new file that you created in the environment would not be similarly copied. So, you could have side-effects in other environments and the package cache.

Comment: @merv if I update the package doesn't conda put the new version beside the old one and start using that instead? I don't see how any changes I've made to the old one would affect the new one, as they are supposedly separate entities. I assumed the same is the case for pip (or at least conda's version of pip).

Comment: @stackexchange_account1111 yes, you are right about that. I was just trying to give an example of potential unintended consequences across environments. Within the single environment it might be okay. The upgrading could depend on how Conda goes about removing the old package. It would be nice if you tested it and reported your finding as an answer.

Comment: @merv Forgot to update, but FWIW my Anaconda install ended up breaking recently (couldn't even boot into base). Idk if that was at all related to me editing the package file. I had to reinstall (thrice, because of some traces from the broken installation that just wouldn't go away). Anaconda/conda are so fragile, it seems, with how often I have to reinstall. Might as well just use vanilla Python.